# Tense in Academic Writing

Tags: tenses, past-tense, academia

What is the correct tense when writing an academic paper? For example, assuming [1] is a reference, are the following sentences correct?

- Alice et al. [1] ***showed*** that ...
- [1] ***shows*** that ...
- We ***show*** the results in Table 1. We ***observe*** that (1) A ***was*** better than B; (2) ...
- As shown in Figure 1, the time taken by A ***is*** comparable to that by B.
- The results ***show*** that ...

Comment: The tense is dependent on what you're describing. Are you talking about results that have been created or tests that resulted in doing more tests or new rules that have resulted from the tests, etc. There's no single tense that all academic papers should be written in.

Comment: @KillingTime I did the experiments before writing the paper. The first two are about tense when referring to a reference. The last three are about presenting my experimental results. I put the results in Table 1 and Figure 1.

Comment: As in language generally, various tenses can come into play, but we can speak of a default tense, which depends on disciplinary style. MLA defaults to present, since books communicate their contents in the present even if their authors are long dead. APA favors past, for reporting experiments and their results once they are done.

Comment: In a scientific paper you are typically describing *in the present* a discovery that you made *in the recent past*. When you refer to prior work, you sometimes want to emphasize that it preceded your own work, e.g. in preparing the commercial samples, we *used* reagent X, as opposed to the less effective reagent Y that *had been used* in the original experiments. In many cases, however, this is a refinement. Present and simple past will often get you by, especially if you use expressions like *before this* and *after this* to clarify the order of events described in the simple past.